# duplicate request id (X-Request-ID) error in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am facing duplicate request id error for Mobile app login

request body

{"email":fddfdvddfdgfddgdfddf6765dfvdf8898ef,"password":"vsgdffd788766lk","timestamp":1682322947068,"ct":1682322947068}

HTTP Header Manager

X-Request-Id    afffbc5c-981d-491b-a496-50a06f5f1a66

getting below Error message in Jmeter response

{"Status":409."error":duplicate request id detected - afffbc5c-981d-491b-a496-50a06f5f1a66}

Please help me overcome the duplicate error issue

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you've already sent the request ID `afffbc5c-981d-491b-a496-50a06f5f1a66` and the system under test doesn't allow it.

I can think of 2 possible options:

1. If the `X-Request-Id` value comes from the server at some point earlier you need to extract it using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace the value in the HTTP Header Manager with the variable from the Post-Processor. The process is known as **[correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)** and there is a lot of information on it in the Internet
2. If you just need to send a new unique value with each request consider replacing this `afffbc5c-981d-491b-a496-50a06f5f1a66` with [`${__UUID()}` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)  and it will generate a new value each time you will call it.

Answer (score 0):

`Request-Id afffbc5c-981d-491b-a496-50a06f5f1a66` is a dynamic value in your case. This will keep on changing with every user every iteration so this needs to handled using JMeter post processor - Regular Expression Extractor.

[image: Regular Expression Extractor1]

Please make use of internet to see how Regular expression extractor works.